# Installation of ROS-velodyne-Package

Tags: ros, installation, yaml, package, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm new to ROS, so don't be mad :-)

I want to install the velodyne_driver(actually the whole velodyne related stuff), and my best guess was, that this command would do that:

rosinstall $ROS_WORKSPACE http://utexas-art-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stacks/velodyne/velodyne_driver

This is the error I get:

ERROR in config: Invalid multiproject yaml format in [http://utexas-art-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stacks/velodyne/velodyne_driver]: while scanning a simple key
in "", line 2, column 1
could not found expected ':'
in "", line 3, column 40

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
ROS: Fuerte

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35320/installation-of-ros-velodyne-package/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Ubuntu 12.04 Fuerte, there is a binary package already available:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-velodyne
```

For building the latest trunk from source, I recommend `rosws`:

```
roslocate info velodyne | rosws merge -
```

As always, use the trunk at your own risk. It is pretty stable right now. In fact, there is one bug fix there that is not yet released (but coming soon).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosinstall seems to be here: http://utexas-art-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rosinstall/utexas-art.rosinstall

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-31**:
That works, but checks out several other large stacks that many people will not need. I will create a velodyne-only rosinstall file in that same directory for this purpose.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-31**:
There is now a  http://utexas-art-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rosinstall/velodyne.rosinstall